# Automat acess to next page using selenium and python

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

I am currently writing a python selenium script to scrape the "Likibu.com",it is a website that offers short-term accommodation such as Airbnb, booking ... I have successfully got all data that exists in the first page and save them in a csv file, but the problem is that there are 37 pages and I would like to scrap also the data that exists in these pages. I managed this code as below :

```
driver.get("https://www.likibu.com/")
page = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")
driver.get("https://www.likibu.com/{0}".format(soup.find(rel=re.compile("nofollow")).attrs["href"]))
```

You find here the source code of the web page:

```html
<ul class="pagination">
<li class="disabled"><a href="#">«</a></li>
<li class="active"><a class="" rel="nofollow" href="https://www.likibu.com/fr/search/39tuzgbpnycdv7tkj102g?guests=2&amp;destination_id=4094&amp;page=1">1</a></li>
<li><a class="" rel="nofollow" href="https://www.likibu.com/fr/search/39tuzgbpnycdv7tkj102g?guests=2&amp;destination_id=4094&amp;page=37">37</a></li>
<li><a class="" rel="nofollow" href="https://www.likibu.com/fr/search/39tuzgbpnycdv7tkj102g?guests=2&amp;destination_id=4094&amp;page=2">»</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you are scrapping multiple pages, you have to figure out how the url is changing. In your case:

```
root = 'https://www.likibu.com/fr/search/39yrzgbpnycdv7tkj132g?guests=2&page='

page_number = 0
while true:
    page_number +=1
    try: 
        url = root + str(page_number)
        ### CODE #####
    except:
        ### terminare / print something ####
```

Note: I added '&page=' to the link you posted. eventhough, it doesn't show in the url for the first page. It still exit. you you add '&page=1', it will give toy the first page.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed that using boucle while
while True:

```
    if not driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Suivant')]"):
        break
    link=WebDriverWait(driver, 1530).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Suivant")))
    link.click()
    next_page = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#pnnext')
    next_page.click()
    time.sleep(5)"""
```